# cx_freeze not working with python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I'm trying to convert a python file to an exe using cx_freeze. In the command prompt I'm in the directory that holds the file I'm trying to convert, but when I type in: Python `setup.py` build. It gives the error

> error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory 'Main.py'

Here is the code in the setup file.

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name = "Name",
    version = "3.1",
    description = "Description",
    executables = [Executable("Main.py", base = "Win32GUI")])
```

Any ideas on why it would be saying this is appreciated!

Comment: what is the name of the `.py` file you're trying to convert? I'm assuming it's *not* `Main.py` (like the script is looking for)

Answer (score 0):

Try using an absolute path for `Main.py`